# How to proceed to build custom JS components

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am very new to Foundation and I would like to know which Foundation 6 bundle (Sites, Apps) would be the best if I wanted to build my own set of JS components?

I read on the website that there are AngularJS and Foundation's own JS components but I don't want to use either.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking which bundle includes no javascript functionality so you can write all your own?

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for.

Comment: download Zurb Foundation 6 [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/complete)  then remove the javascript files. Good luck.